# how to solve the close() was never explicitly called on database error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have gone through a number of answers here and on other blogs. And they where suggesting I call the close() function on all open connections. which I did But still getting this error. I have an application that first tries to count the number of tips that exist in sqlite database table, if there no rows it returns 0. And if there any rows then it returns the number of rows. here is my code

```
public int count_tips() {

    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("select * from "
            + DATABASE_TIPS_TABLE, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getInt(0) == 0) {

            cursor.close();
            return 0;
        } else {

            cursor.close();
            return cursor.getCount();
        }
    } else {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

But i keep getting the error below, where could be going wrong. Atleast I think i have closed all the database connects that I opened. But cant figure out where am going wrong.

```
03-02 11:09:00.457: D/Cursor(4712): Table name   : null
03-02 11:09:00.457: D/Cursor(4712): SQL          : SQLiteQuery: select * from tips
03-02 11:09:00.457: I/dalvikvm(4712): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
03-02 11:09:00.457: I/dalvikvm(4712): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4054c690 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
03-02 11:09:00.464: I/dalvikvm(4712):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:620)
03-02 11:09:00.464: I/dalvikvm(4712):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-02 11:09:00.472: E/Database(4712): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.jingo.willappsug.yamba/databases/yambasqlite' 
03-02 11:09:00.472: E/Database(4712): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
03-02 11:09:00.472: E/Database(4712):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
```

Comment: How can you return cursor.getCount() if you've closed the cursor on the previous line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try putting the `close()` call in a `finally` block with a `try/catch`?

```
public int count_tips() {
   try {
       ... // your code here
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       // handle the exception properly
   }
   finally {
       cursor.close()
   }
}
```

Comment: worked just fine, after three days trying to fix this error. thanks

Comment: In addition, even if you don't plan to handle the exception here (say your method declares that it throws exceptions) it's still good practice to put try and finally blocks without the catch block

Comment: new problem, I cannot insert data into the DATABASE_TIPS_TABLE anymore

Comment: JSONArray tipsJSon_array = json.getJSONArray("tips");
      for (int i = 0; i < tipsJSon_array.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject tipsObj = tipsJSon_array
         .getJSONObject(i);
       serverTipsCategory = tipsObj.getString("category");
       serverHead = tipsObj.getString("head");
       serverBody = tipsObj.getString("body");

       // pushing info into database
       db.open();
       db.insertTips(serverTipsCategory, serverHead,
         serverBody);
       db.close();

Comment: public long insertTips(String serverTipsCategory, String serverHead,
   String serverBody) {
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(KEY_CATEGORY, serverTipsCategory);
  cv.put(KEY_HEAD, serverHead);
  cv.put(KEY_BODY, serverBody);

  return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TIPS_TABLE, null, cv);
 }